# Is there any way to know name of keys in json object from android app?

Tags: android, facebook

I have an app which requests infomation to facebook then get infromation from facebook.

Facebook sends information to my app by the type of json object.

Since this information was not created by me, I dont know key names of this json object.

Is there anyway to know json object key names from android app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, you're looking to parse dynamic JSON keys. Check this out: [How to parse a dynamic JSON key in a Nested JSON result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304002/how-to-parse-a-dynamic-json-key-in-a-nested-json-result)