# Creating pojo classes for parsing android json

Tags: android

I am getting following json in response from an api:

```
    {
  "0": {
    "review_id": "2",
    "ad_id": "27",
    "user_id": "2",
    "name": "John1",
    "rating": "4",
    "title": "Nice object1",
    "comment": "Nice",
    "status": "1",
    "created_date": "2016-12-12 15:46:18",
    "modified_date": "2016-12-12 21:17:24",
    "modified_by": "0",
    "add_title": "Sell new new plot"
  },
  "1": {
    "review_id": "3",
    "ad_id": "27",
    "user_id": "2",
    "name": "John2",
    "rating": "3",
    "title": "Nice object2",
    "comment": "Nice",
    "status": "1",
    "created_date": "2016-12-12 12:46:18",
    "modified_date": "2016-12-12 21:17:24",
    "modified_by": "0",
    "add_title": "Sell new new plot"
  },
  "2": {
    "review_id": "4",
    "ad_id": "27",
    "user_id": "2",
    "name": "John3",
    "rating": "4",
    "title": "Nice object3",
    "comment": "Nice",
    "status": "1",
    "created_date": "2016-12-12 11:46:18",
    "modified_date": "2016-12-12 21:17:24",
    "modified_by": "0",
    "add_title": "Sell new new plot"
  },
  "status": 1,
  "count": 3,
  "msg": "Total Number of found records "
}
```

When i try to create pojo classes of this json, it does not give correct classes. Can someone please help me how to parse this json? 
Thanks.

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: how did you create POJO classes

Comment: @askarcali [pojocreated](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B80WwXxkG7BkQjV0NXpvMG1UYlU) i  used the website mentioned by Raghunandan and got this pojo, in this i am getting 1,2,3, it is specifically for this json, not a general solution, i hope u get what i am trying to say..

Comment: I still didn't get what actually you want. Do you want to know how to map this to model ?

Comment: @askarcali yes i want to know how to map this json to model.

Comment: I guess you are looking for [parsing dynamic JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855347/parsing-dynamic-json-in-android)