# Dynamic JSON Parsing error : expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1, how to resolve

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

I am Parsing Dynamic JSON, so it's more complicated to Decompile using POJO (Model Classes)

Is there any Convenient way to do this, provide suggestions to me.

Here is the Issue

```
public class Post {

    @SerializedName("Resource")
    @Expose
    private Resource onlineResource;

    public Resource getResource() {
        return onlineResource;
    }

      public void setResource(Resource resource) {
         this.onlineResource = resource;
      }

    }


    public class Resource {

    @SerializedName(value = "_xmlns:xlink",alternate = "xmlns:xlink")
    @Expose
    private Object xmlnsXlink;
    @SerializedName(value = "_xlink:href",alternate = "xlink:href")
    @Expose
    private Object xlinkHref;

    public Object getXmlnsXlink() {
        return xmlnsXlink;
    }

    public void setXmlnsXlink(Object xmlnsXlink) {
        this.xmlnsXlink = xmlnsXlink;
    }

    public Object getXlinkHref() {
        return xlinkHref;
    }

    public void setXlinkHref(Object xlinkHref) {
        this.xlinkHref = xlinkHref;
    }

}
```

for Resource Class Sometimes get JSON

like :

```
   {
    "Resource": "abcdefgh",
   }
```

alternatively 
like :

```
{ 
  "Resource" :
              {
              "_xmlns:xlink":"xyz",
              "_xlink:href":"abc"
              },
}
```

So how could I parse this type of Random(Dynamic) Json?

Comment: you can do manual parsing based on the type and then put data in model class.

Comment: i have  tried but i have very large and nested JSON Response  so is not convenient way to parse Dynamic Json

Comment: Paste your response JSON

Comment: unable to paste whole JSON here.Some part of response :
"DCPType": {
"HTTP": {
 "Get": {
  "Resource": {
  "_xmlns:xlink": "dfds",
  "_xlink:href": "214df"
        }
       },
       "Post": {
        "OnlineResource": {
         "_xmlns:xlink": "fdsf",
         "_xlink:href": "0124fs"
        }
       }
      }
     }

Answer (score 0):

you just change the variable data type from Object To String :

```
private Object xmlnsXlink;   TO    private String xmlnsXlink;
```

And

```
private Object xlinkHref;  TO  private String xlinkHref;
```

Comment: Thanks but there is no fix response it will change just Key is fixed that's why i have used "Object" class Type over there

Comment: if your key is not fixed with any predefined type then you have no any option to parse json dynamically, you must have to parse json manually.

Comment: my key is fixed as  xmlnslink but not fixed that will appear in JSON or not,if appear than will in JsonObject/Array or simple String.

Comment: yes my mean is your key is fixed but value type is not fixed then you can not use this dynamic way.

Answer (score 0):

First use this class as your Resource class

```
    public class Resource {

    @SerializedName("_xmlns:xlink")
    @Expose
    private String xmlnsXlink;
    @SerializedName("_xlink:href")
    @Expose
    private String xlinkHref;

    public String getXmlnsXlink() {
    return xmlnsXlink;
    }

    public void setXmlnsXlink(String xmlnsXlink) {
    this.xmlnsXlink = xmlnsXlink;
    }

    public String getXlinkHref() {
    return xlinkHref;
    }

public void setXlinkHref(String xlinkHref) {
this.xlinkHref = xlinkHref;
}

}
```

For variable json at certain points you need to manually parse json wherever json type is variable(string/object)using this :

```
json instanceof JSONObject
```

and then you can pass it's value in a model class

Comment: thanks but it throws  exception ::  expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1 which i asked this question here.
and  apart class is working properly with JSON having this Key value pair. as i mentioned

Comment: That exception is for Resource object/string

Comment: Yeah but sometime i received Object with Key-Value pair and sometimes i received simple  String value instead of Object 
like :  {
    "Resource": "abcdefgh",
   }

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible if you are using JSON parsing library such as Gson. You have to parse the JSON manually as suggested here: [Parsing dynamic JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855347/parsing-dynamic-json-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for your time,It's also not helping me at all. as i mentioned i have very large Dynamic JSON response. for Now i would like ask that suppose i created Model class and get the resopnse different how can parse it

Comment: This just isn't true at all; it is absolutely possible to encounter similar errors in Gson.