# How to parse json Object having dynamic keys using retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit2

Below is my sample JSON which I am getting from server I am using GSON annotation :-

```
{
    "FAMILY": [{
        "G": "0",
        "Red": [{
            "G": "89.5140282228858",
            "B": "75.6247151421873",
            "R": "190.744678043659"
        }, {
            "G": "159.384178987744",
            "B": "142.476648231788",
            "R": "237.397293369723"
        }]
    }, {
        "G": "0",
        "Blue": [{
            "G": "89.5140282228858",
            "B": "75.6247151421873",
            "R": "190.744678043659"
        }, {
            "G": "159.384178987744",
            "B": "142.476648231788",
            "R": "237.397293369723"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information : what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` for parsing json with dynamic keys. this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796662/using-gson-to-parse-a-json-with-dynamic-key-and-value-in-android) might help you. which uses gson to parse json.
check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267749/how-to-parse-a-json-with-dynamic-key-in-android-by-using-gson) link also. check out the documentation of gson [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples).