# JSON Parsing in Java Webservice of multiple JSONObjects in JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

This is my JSON string,

```
{
"listmain":{ 
     "16":[{"brandid":"186"},{"brandid":"146"},{"brandid":"15"}],
     "17":[{"brandid":"1"}],
     "18":[{"brandid":"12"},{"brandid":"186"}],

           }
 }
```

I need to get values in "16","17","18" tag and add values and ids("16","17","18") to two ArrayList.

What i meant is,
when we take "16", the following process should happen,

```
 List<String> lsubid = new ArrayList<String>();
 List<String> lbrandid = new ArrayList<String>();
 for(int i=0;i<number of elements in "16";i++) {
     lsubid.add("16");
     lbrandid.add("ith value in tag "16" ");
 }
```

finally the values in lsubid will be---> [16,16,16]

the values in lbrandid will be---> [186,146,15]

Can anyone please help me to complete this.

Comment: You can get your JSON keys with this function : http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys()
I think it will help you :)

Comment: Create a simple pojo class, use gson to parse the json into an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JSONObject keys()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys%28%29) to get the key and then iterate each key to get to the dynamic value.

You can parse the `JSON` like this

```
JSONObject responseDataObj = new JSONObject(responseData);
JSONObject listMainObj = responseDataObj.getJSONObject("listmain");
Iterator keys = listMainObj.keys();
while(keys.hasNext()) {
   // loop to get the dynamic key
   String currentDynamicKey = (String)keys.next();
   //store key in an arraylist which is 16,17,...
   // get the value of the dynamic key
   JSONArray currentDynamicValue = listMainObj.getJSONArray(currentDynamicKey);
   int jsonrraySize = currentDynamicValue.length();
   if(jsonrraySize > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonrraySize; i++) {
            JSONObject brandidObj = currentDynamicValue.getJSONObject(i);
            String brandid = brandidObj.getString("brandid");
            System.out.print("Brandid = " + brandid);
            //store brandid in an arraylist
        }                   
    }
}
```

[***Source of this answer***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304002/how-to-parse-a-dynamic-json-key-in-a-nested-json-result)

Comment: Thank you sir, but i tried this but have got an Exception

org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["brandid"] not found.

Comment: @user3841250: can u post `logcat` in ur question

Comment: got error in this line,
String brandid = brandidObj.getString("brandid");


org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["brandid"] not found.
 at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:473)
 at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:654)

Comment: Thanx alot sir it works, there was some problem with my database connection code. Now it works. :)