# How to fetch the distinct values from JSONObject in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I have the output in following JSONObject format. I want to fetch each and every value in this JSONObject. How can I do it? Need help! Thank you in advance.

```
{
      "410": 19082,
      "443": 19097,
      "667": 19172
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7304091/2562861

Comment: I tried using Iterator class and then tried to fetch the value using keys.next(). But no luck. :(

Comment: Post the code that you tried and the issue you have with that.

Comment: @PrerakSola I am trying something like this `JSONObject newjsonobject1 = null;
                for(int i = 0;i<newjsonarray1.length();i++)
                {
                    newjsonobject1 = newjsonarray1.getJSONObject(i);
                }
                Iterator<String> keys = newjsonobject1.keys();
                while(keys.hasNext())
                {
                    String current = (String)keys.next();
                    String value = newjsonobject1.getString(current);
                    Log.e("Fetched value________",value);
                }`

Comment: @Shijil I saw that post and it is the same as I am trying to implement, but not working.

Comment: Got the solution guys, the code I posted is working now. It was an error on my server side scripting. I just changed the signature on server side of JSONObject. Thank You! Above posted is the code to fetch the random distinct values in the JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

you can used below login for parsing key's value's of JSON

```
 String json ="{\n" +
            "      \"410\": 19082,\n" +
            "      \"443\": 19097,\n" +
            "      \"667\": 19172\n" +
            " }";
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
        for(int i = 0; i<obj.length(); i++){
            Log.e("json parse", "Key = " + obj.names().getString(i) + " value = " + obj.get(obj.names().getString(i)));
        }

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: The output is not static all the times. It is dynamic. So you suggesting to use StringBuilder for dynamic?

Comment: sorry i am not suggesting to use StringBuilder . try iterator for this