# Android Retrofit reading a JSON object

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a clean and simple question how to read this using Android Retrofit 2.0

```
  {
  "status": true,

 "body": {

    "expertises": {
      "1": "Family Law",
      "2": "Land and Asset",
      "3": "Sexual Offense"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to read "expertises"

I have used model classes as follows: 
Expertises:

```
 public class Expertises {
    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("expertises")
    ExpertisesResponse expertisesResponse;

    public ExpertisesResponse getExpertisesResponse() {
        return expertisesResponse;
    }

    public void setExpertisesResponse(ExpertisesResponse expertisesResponse) {
        this.expertisesResponse = expertisesResponse;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

ExpertisesResponse:

```
public class ExpertisesResponse {

    @SerializedName("1")
    private String expertiseOne;
    @SerializedName("2")
    private String expertiseTwo;
    @SerializedName("3")
    private String expertiseThree;

    public String getExpertiseOne() {
        return expertiseOne;
    }

    public ExpertisesResponse(String expertiseOne, String expertiseTwo, String   expertiseThree) {
        this.expertiseOne = expertiseOne;
        this.expertiseTwo = expertiseTwo;
        this.expertiseThree = expertiseThree;
    }



    public String getExpertiseTwo() {
        return expertiseTwo;
    }

    public String getExpertiseThree() {
        return expertiseThree;
    }

    public void setExpertiseOne(String expertiseOne) {
        this.expertiseOne = expertiseOne;
    }

    public void setExpertiseTwo(String expertiseTwo) {
        this.expertiseTwo = expertiseTwo;
    }

    public void setExpertiseThree(String expertiseThree) {
        this.expertiseThree = expertiseThree;
    }
}
```

But I am getting Exception NullPointer for ExpertisesResposne. PLease I want some improvement or correction if anything is wrong.

This is how I called :

```
 ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<Expertises> getExpertises = apiInterface.getExpertise();
        getExpertises.enqueue(new Callback<Expertises>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Expertises> call, Response<Expertises> response) {

                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.body().getExpertisesResponse().getExpertiseOne(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Expertises> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: have  you created model class for that ?

Comment: Yes but it will be better if you can tell because i have confusion on "expertises"

Comment: Does the number of expertises change over time? Are there always 3 of these?

Comment: They will change over time, why anything wrong with JSON it will not work if more values are added in future?

Comment: How do you make the request, show us that part of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed class `Body` covering class `ExpertisesResponse`. Should be like:

```
class Body {

@SerializedName("expertises")
    ExpertisesResponse expertisesResponse;

}
```

And class `Expertises`

```
public class Expertises {
    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("body")
    Body body;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! Now one last thing is What if in future these "expertises" in json response increase? How to accommodate that scenario?

Comment: If values in `expertises` change. Have 2 ways to do: 1-restructure your json returned with unchnaged `key`. 2. Parse dynamic keys manually(you need to parse manually) [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304002/how-to-parse-a-dynamic-json-key-in-a-nested-json-result. I think if you use retrofit with auto parsing, you suggest you the first way.

Comment: OK Thanks RoShan Shan :)