# Handles json objects without knowing the attribute name and number of attributes

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I tried to process the request with the example below:

```
"type" : "NEWS",
"content" : {
    "title" : "Test Message",
    "message" : "This is a message",
    "buttonCaption" : "Click me"
}
```

Or maybe:

```
"type" : "NEWS",
"content" : {
    "title" : "Test Message",
    "message" : "This is a message",
    "buttonCaption" : "Click me",
    "anotherField" : "values"
}
```

Sometime maybe:

```
"type" : "NEWS",
"content" : {
    "name" : "Test Message",
    "anotherProperties" : "This is a message",
    "ohMyGodAnotherFields" : "Click me"
}
```

So I cannot create a particular Object.
How can I handle it in Spring controller?

Comment: it looks to be a duplicate: of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304002/how-to-parse-a-dynamic-json-key-in-a-nested-json-result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JsonNode` in your resource class like:

```
public class Foo {
    private String type;
    private JsonNode content;
    // ...
}
```

And accept it as `@RequestBody` in your controller:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Foo> foo(@RequestBody Foo foo){
   // do something with your foo...
}
```

You can read more aboot JsonNode [here.](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the keys, using java.util.Iterator.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(JSONString);
Iterator keys = jsonObj.keys();
while (keys.hasNext()) {
     String keyStr = keys.next().toString();
     String value = jsonObj.getStrin(keyStr);
}
```

or You can try this:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(JSONString);
if (jsonObj.has("key")) {
    String value = jsonObj.getString("key");
}
```